# Highlight some rows of my table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to highlight some rows of my table. This highlight is based on the rows present in my `response` object. This object can be as follow:

```
<table id="ListRequests" class="table table-striped">    
    <tbody>
        <tr id="13955">
            <td>JEAN DUPONT</td>                
            <td>ACLIMEX SPRL</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
        var id = $("tbody tr", response).attr('id');
        var cols = $('#' + id + ' td');
        cols.effect("highlight", {}, 30000);
```

This works fine only if my response object contains only 1 row. Now I need to be able to highlight more than 1 rows at a time. So for example with the response object below:

```
<table id="ListRequests" class="table table-striped">    
    <tbody>
        <tr id="13955">
            <td>JEAN DUPONT</td>                
            <td>ACLIMEX SPRL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="13954">
            <td>MIKE GIVER</td>                
            <td>ARGO INTERNATIONAL CORP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea how to adapt my javascript code for that purpose ?

Comment: It's unclear how you intend to select the row to highlight. The code you've posted will always find the first row's ID, and then highlight the `<td>` elements within that row.

Comment: Please note that I find the id in the `response` object BUT I perform the highlight effect on the DOM. At present it works pretty well when the response object contains only 1 row. If it contains 2 or more, only the 1st one is highlighted. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it the way you are doing it, than you need to use each

```
var trs = $("tbody tr", response);
trs.each( function () {
    var id = this.id,
        cols = $('#' + id + ' td');
    cols.effect("highlight", {}, 30000);
});
```

Better off returning a JSON object with ids to select.

Comment: If you read my javascript code you will see that I find the id in my `response` object BUT I perform the highlight effect on the DOM. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's perfect for my purpose. I know this is better with JSON but there is a reason for proceeding like this (out of scope of this question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet.

The idea is to scrap the ids from the response you get by looping the `tr` nodes, from these ids build a css selector for the nodes you are interested in, and finally highlight all them.

```js
function highlight(response){
  // retrieve the ids from the response
  var ids = $(response).find("tbody tr").map(function(){
    // `this` will be the trs one after the other.
    // `map` will put all returned values in an array.
    return this.getAttribute("id");
  }).get();
  // build the css selector
  var selector = "#" + ids.join(",#");
  // highlight the corresponding nodes
  $(selector).effect("highlight", {}, 30000);
}

// Call highlight with your response example.
highlight('<table id="ListRequests" class="table table-striped"><tbody><tr id="13955"><td>JEAN DUPONT</td><td>ACLIMEX SPRL</td></tr><tr id="13954"><td>MIKE GIVER</td><td>ARGO INTERNATIONAL CORP</td></tr></tbody></table>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="ListRequests" class="table table-striped">    
    <tbody>
        <tr id="13955">
            <td>JEAN DUPONT</td>                
            <td>ACLIMEX SPRL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="13954">
            <td>MIKE GIVER</td>                
            <td>ARGO INTERNATIONAL CORP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1211">
            <td>OTHER ONE</td>                
            <td>MUSN'T BE HIGHLIGHTED</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr` returns a single value, regardless how many elements are matched by the proceeding selector.

If you want to map every selected element to an ID and return array, you need `map`:

```
var ids = $("tbody tr", response).map(function (i, e) { return $(e).attr('id'); });
```

Once you have your list of IDs, you can iterate over that list, and highlight the matching rows in the DOM:

```
ids.forEach(function (id) {
  var cols = $('#' + id + ' td');
  cols.effect("highlight", {}, 30000);
});
```